# AndroidX Setting Background Color on Button has NO Effect

Tags: android, androidx

I usually set the background color on a button simply in XML using android:background or programatically using setBackgroundColor but now with the AndroidX library (i assume...), these has no effect on the button color

it seems that setting android:backgroundTint is working but this works only for APIs 21 and above

how can i achieve this ?

example:

Shouldnt this produce a layout with a red backgrounded button...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#af2222"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Never heard about such an error before in Androidx, can you show your XML and JAVA code please?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån a simple layout with nothing but a button and having set the button background as such: android:background="#fff" for example has no effect.... i can show you this xml but its as simple as that

Comment: But this is a normal button (support.design), but in the question you've stated about Androidx?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån your are correct!.. but does this mean i cannot use the Button(support Design anymore)?.. i got confused since its available to be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [svkaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519618/1950784) mentioned, i used `app:backgroundTint="#af2222"` in xml to solve the issue.

Programatically, i used this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) statusButton.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(MY_COLOR)

else  statusButton.setBackgroundColor(MY_COLOR)
```

Also to note, this is required on Both material and support design button since the `android:background="#fff"` on both now seems to have no effect

Answer (score 4):

I use this in android x instead of `<Button` and background color will changes

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Done"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add style to your button tag as if you are using Androidx with material design.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
```

This style will let you set primaryColor as background color.

So your whole code will look like:

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Messages"
   android:minWidth="200dp"
   app:cornerRadius=”16dp”
   app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_setting" 
   app:cornerRadius="@dimen/_16sdp"
   app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
   app:iconTint="@color/light_pitch" 
   app:iconPadding="-12dp"
  />
```

Cheers!

Comment: In my XML there is just "Button". IDE says it's from android.widget.TextView. Whatever... Material styles seem to work. I had Borderless from AppCompat before that resulted in white text on white background...

Answer (score 2):

You can try using: `app:backgroundTint="#af2222"` and remove `android:background="#af2222"` it should support <21 also